Enable DNS Windows 10 host for WSL2
By default, WSL2 appears to pick up the Windows Host IP Address as its autoconfigured DNS server.
This can be seen by inspecting the contents of /etc/resolv.conf.
For example
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 172.21.48.1

This would be fine, if there was a DNS server running at address 172.21.48.1. In my particular case, this host is a Windows 10 machine. It is host for WSL2, Docker Desktop and some Docker Containers.
The usual "fix" for this is to modify /etc/resolv.conf, and use setattr +i to prevent the file from being modified. The file /etc/wsl.conf also has to be changed to disable auto-configuration of /etc/resolv.conf.
I suspect there is a better solution to this. If the host 172.21.48.1 really was a DNS server, in other words if it was running a DNS server software, then I would guess the problem would be simply resolved, because DNS requests would be forwarded correctly.
Is there a way to install a DNS Server on a Windows 10 machine? I only managed to find information relating to Windows Server platforms.
Alternatively, it could be a local network configuration issue relating to DNS. It might be that the DNS servers which are being used by the Windows 10 host to obtain IP address information are not correctly forwarding information about which DNS servers should be used. (Although this seems a bit unlikely. It seems more likely to be a problem with Windows 10 not forwarding the correct DNS server addresses to WSL2 containers.)

Something like this? https://maradns.samiam.org

Thanks for re-opening the question

“Is there a way to install a DNS Server on a Windows 10 machine?” - Of course there is. Unless it’s a bona fide feature of Windows Server it can be installed on Windows.

@Ramhound How is that helpful?
